# Symbolic matrix mutiplication error (Ryacas)

Tags: r, matrix, yacas

I would like to do symbolic matrix operations with `Ryacas` using a function that converts base `R` matrices to `Ryacas` format. The result of the function seems to match `Ryacas` format. But when I attempt to multiply the matrices, the error

```
# Error in aa %*% aa : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

throws. The code below is a minimal example that shows the case.

Any suggestion, please?

```
library(Ryacas)

conv.mat <- function(x) {
  conv <- lapply(1:nrow(x), function(i) paste0(x[i, ], collapse = ", "))
  conv <- paste0("List(", paste0("List(", unlist(conv), ")", collapse = ", "), ")")
  noquote(conv)
}

# Writing a matrix manually for Ryacas format

a <- List(List(1, 2), List(3, 7))
a * a
# expression(list(list(7, 16), list(24, 55)))


# Writing a matrix in R and convert it to Ryacas format by the function conv.mat

aa <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 7), 2, byrow = TRUE)
aa <- conv.mat(aa)
# [1] List(List(1, 2), List(3, 7))

aa * aa
# Error in aa * aa : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, to multiply `Ryacas` matrices you want `aa * aa` rather than `aa %*% aa`. But that alone doesn't help in your case as `conv.mat` doesn't give exactly what we need (an expression).

We may use, e.g.,

```
conv.mat <- function(x)
  do.call(List, lapply(1:nrow(x), function(r) do.call(List, as.list(x[r, ]))))
```

Then

```
M <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 7), 2, byrow = TRUE)
M %*% M
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    7   16
# [2,]   24   55
M <- conv.mat(M)
M * M
# expression(list(list(7, 16), list(24, 55)))
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually in my original code, I used `aa * aa`, but I overlooked it here. I tried to use `parse(text=conv)` in the function to get an `expression`, but it was not work.